# No questions asked but banned from Programmers

Tags: support, post-ban

There are other users who have been banned from Stack Exchange sites. My problem is different.
I just logged into Programmers, and I haven't asked or commented anything before within Programmers. When I tried clicking Ask Question I got the following response:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

I can ask questions in Stack Overflow as well as here. Now what would be the reason? If that is a mistake any way to revert it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have asked three questions on Programmers, all of them deleted:

- [Looking for an RSS Video Feed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185234/looking-for-an-rss-video-feed)
- [Job Application Assesments - Advice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/210876/job-application-assesments-advice)
- [Q: Applying for a patent or copyright](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212612/q-applying-for-a-patent-or-copyright)

The first two were downvoted and closed, and the third one you deleted yourself a couple of minutes after you posted it.

I don't think there's room for improvement in any of your questions, all three are quite off topic. Thus, your better option to get out of the ban would be to post a few *good* answers, and improve others' posts through editing.

Comment: user1292095 if you want direct links to your deleted questions, let me know.

Comment: I would like to get direct links to my deleted questions please. That would be really good.

Comment: @user1292095 Added the links to the answer.

Comment: consider adding a reference to detailed guidance at MSO: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/165773)